# Contents of Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet "cell" to be exported as HTML in CSV

Tags: html, excel, csv

So I'm building a content spreadsheet in Excel containing a bunch of news stories that will be automatically inserted into an email. Once I complete the spreadsheet, I export it as a CSV. From there I upload the CSV into a SQL table which get's read to build an email newsletter. All of that is said for important context of my question... which is as follows:

Is there anyway to covert Bold, Italic and link styles to HTML upon export to a CSV?

The use case here is marketers (not developers) will be filling out this Excel spreadsheet to build their newsletter. They only need basic controls in formatting the content (Bold, Underline and Links). so for example I have one column called "Description". Now one of the items has a description such as:

"This is going to be the **greatest weekend** of all time!"

"greatest weekend" here is bold. When I export the CSV I want it to export as:

`"This is going to be the <b>greatest weekend</b> of all time!"`

I'm aware I can physically type the `<b>`, `<em>` and `<a>` tags. But these marketers will be confused by this. Any ideas?

Comment: HTML is not CSV. If you want HTML syntax exported as CSV then you will have to change the strings before exporting.

Comment: How do you manage the links in excel?  It's not like you can just link part of a cell's content.

Comment: @tim, Your right, I thought I could link part of a cell but I can't. It has to be the whole thing. 

I guess I will have to physically write the HTML. Thanks,